# how to share a video from my website to WhatsApp

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5-video, whatsapp

I want to share video and image from my site to whatsapp, can its possible. Realted to this I searched google but I am only able to find this link :-
https://github.com/kriskbx/whatsapp-sharing and in this link there is specify that we can't share image and video from our website to whatsapp. Please clear

Answer (score 0):

You could send a link to a web page there the image/video is hosted via deep link:

```
<a href="WhatsApp://send?text=This is the content the receiver gets via WhatsApp">Share via WhatsApp</a>
```

And sending media directly **wont work**

Comment: from this we can only send text but I want to send  video and image from my website to whatsapp

Comment: Hi Renu,where u able to share videos?I am looking to share videos